# Count the number of rows in csv column containing 'male'

Tags: powershell, csv

I am looking to count the amount of male members in a CSV file of 500 entries. The file is only one sheet and looks like this:

```
Klantnummer Nationaliteit   Geslacht    Title
1           Dutch           female      Ms.
2           Dutch           female      Mrs.
3           Dutch           female      Mrs.
4           Dutch           female      Dr.
5           Dutch           male        Mr.
```

I can't find any example of this on google or stackoverflow, can you please help?

Comment: What do you mean with *"I can't find any example"*?

Comment: `(Import-Csv 'yourPath' | Where-Object Geslacht -eq male | Measure-Object).Count`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I get a count of 0. I tried putting 'geslacht' and 'male' in quotes, this didn't do it unfortunately. Thanks for the swift response though!

Comment: _The file is only one sheet_: CSV-files can only contain one "sheet". It's a table of data.

Comment: Then its not a csv but maybe a tab separated file?

Comment: It is a CSV, I double checked just now ;)

Comment: Then you do something wrong, my code will work if you have a csv. You should post one or two example rows of the actual file

Comment: I opened the file in notepad, it turns out all the cells are separated by a ; . Could it be possible that your code reads the whole row and not just the cell entry for the right column?

Comment: It worked! After you edited your answer, thanks a million!

Comment: So I will post my code as an answer, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Command gives the Number of male entries:

```
(Import-Csv 'yourPath' -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object {$_.geslacht -eq "male"} | Measure-Object).Count
```

Make sure to give the correct Path and the correct Delimiter used in the .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You can im import the file using the `Import-CSV` cmdlet. Note that you have to specify the delimiter since you don't use a regular CSV. Then you can filter all records with the desired Geslacht and count it using the `Measure-Object` cmdlet:

```
(Import-Csv 'yourPath' -Delimiter ';'| Where-Object Geslacht -eq male | Measure-Object).Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using `Group-Object` instead of `Measure-Object`:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
    Group-Object 'Geslacht' |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'male' } |
    Select-Object -Expand Count
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$Get_Gender=Import-Csv 'Yourpath'  | Where-Object {$_.geslacht -eq "Male"}

write-host "Number of $($Get_Gender.Geslacht |Select-Object -First 1) are :$(($Get_Gender.Geslacht).count)"
```

Comment: Since the where already has explicitly defined male you could as well write it into Write-Host. Or simply use $Get_Gender[0].Geslacht.

Comment: I tried using Get_Gender[0] before but when you only have one male on your list it only selects the letter "M" so that is why i used select-object -first  1